# Firebase Remove image link value replace with empty string

Tags: angular, function, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am trying to run a function to change a firebase list item value to be an empty string. so I am trying to remove a news post thumb image url from the image value in firebase.

When I post a news item it gets modelled like this and saved into firebase.

```
news: any = {
    title: '',
    shortDescription: "",
    description: "",
    createdAt: Date.now(),
    thumb: ""
  }
```

Whenever Ipost a news item, the image for the post gets saved in firebase storage, then a link to the image gets saved in the 'thumb' in the news item.

Another link gets saved under a node called 'Media' to allow me to view all images added with news posts in a media library sort of view.

When I am viewing the media library I can delete images, what I am trying to do is when I delete an image, I search firebase news posts for a matching image url in the thumb section and I want to remove the link and leave an empty string there in the 'thumb' section.

variables used in the updateNewsImageLink() function below:

```
  news: Array<any>;
  newsDataRef: AngularFireList<any>;
  newsObservable: Observable<any>;
  list: any
```

this.imagePath is the url of the image in firebase storage.

```
    updateNewsImageLink() {
    this.newsDataRef = this.af.list('/news', ref => ref.orderByChild('thumb').equalTo(this.imagePath))
    this.newsObservable = this.newsDataRef.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
      return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
    });
    this.newsObservable.subscribe((res) => {
      this.news = res[0];
      this.list = res;
      this.list.update(this.news, { thumb: ' ' });
    });
  }
```

I am calling this function before I run a previous function which deletes the image itself from firebase storage, so once the image itself gets deleted I then want to leave the news 'thumb' value as an empty string in firebase database.

Comment: "I am calling this function" and what happens when you call it? Does it update anything? Does it show any error?

Comment: I am not getting any errors, but the thumb value does not change in firebase.

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to figure this out myself. what I had to do, was grab the key from the news post of the image that I wanted to delete and then use that to run the function to update the thumb to an empty string.

So in the constructor I added the following:

```
this.newsDataRef = this.af.list('/news', ref => ref.orderByChild('thumb').equalTo(this.imagePath))
          this.newsDataRef.snapshotChanges(['child_added'])
            .subscribe(actions => {
              actions.forEach(action => {
                this.newskey = action.key;
              });
            });
```

This allowed me to grab the key of the news post and assign it to: this.newskey.

I added the newskey:any variable above the constructor.

Now when I run the function below, I simply update the node using the newskey as the reference point.

```
updateNewsImageLink() {
    this.newsDataRef.update(this.newskey, { thumb: '' });
  }
```

Now when managing images in my media library, I can delete the image from firebase storage, from the media library node in the database and now from the news post thumb from the database also.

I hope this can help someone in any way.